# Low-search: How to get the total amount of search results?

Tags: low-search

I am trying to get the total amount of search results available for a given search term. My results are paginated. `total_results` Will give me the total amount displayed in the page, but I need the total amount available in all pages to say something like "Your search term was found in 140 pages"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [native `{absolute_results}` variable](http://ee2docs.com/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#absolute-results). This is shown in [the first example](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/examples#keywords) of the docs.